# Closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `foo`, which is owned by the current function

Tags: rust

What's wrong with the following code?

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let handler = std::thread::spawn(||{
        dbg!(&a+1);
    });
    dbg!(&a);
    handler.join().unwrap();
}
```

It's clear that the spawned thread doesn't outlive the `main` function, so why does it happen? Type system limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is not smart enough for that, use [`scope()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 1;

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            dbg!(&a + 1);
        });
    });

    dbg!(&a);
}
```

Comment: It works for OS threads, thanks. Could you please suggest the similar thing for tokio or actix_web?

Comment: @ababo that way different, in async this is probably an anti pattern, can you provide a snipped of what you would want (make a new question maybe)

Comment: Exactly the same structure, just different spawn with `async {}`.

Comment: @ababo well I don't know what to answer except don't do this pattern in async, it's simply don't make sense and I think that mostly impossible, notice you can like thread, retrieve the value return by a async task with the join handle. Without usecase/practical question I can help more, I can only give random help like in async we use channel to send message we don't share data, https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html.

Comment: No problem, I can use 'async move' and clone the variable. Thank you.

Comment: @ababo You cannot have scoped async tasks because of issues with cancellation.